# React router v5 on navigate away event

Tags: reactjs, react-router, formik

Using `react-router-dom 5.1.2` and `formik 2.0.1` and need to persist `formik.values` when navigate away from **MyForm**. Is there any event like `beforeLocationChange` in react-router? Or what would be the best option to use?

Thanks in advance

[image: Edit react-router useFormikContext]

Answer (score 0):

you can save the form info in your parent class/app class by creating an onChangeHandler in the parent component, then pass it as props to your MyForm component.

```
<MyForm onChangeHandler={() => this.onChangeHandler(e)} formData={this.state.formData} />
```

You must bind your form value to your props value, then you store your data in your state so it can persist outside MyForm

I think you would like to study react-redux https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux — this might be a better solution if you want to scale your app and don't want the chaos that is to update children props (at some scale, passing information between components can make your app to have some unexpected behavior)

Comment: Thank you Celso. I'm using Apollo client and will save form values in Apollo cache. However, I don't need to update Apollo cache immediately after each change in formik values. That's why I'm looking for an event to catch before route change. What would you think?